# trouble trying to build opengl superbible example code

Tags: opengl, makefile, cmake

So I got the superbible 6th edition, and am trying to cmake and make the example code framework, but get this error:

```
Scanning dependencies of target sb6
[  1%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/sb6.dir/src/sb6/sb6.cpp.o
[  2%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/sb6.dir/src/sb6/sb6ktx.cpp.o
[  3%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/sb6.dir/src/sb6/sb6object.cpp.o
[  5%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/sb6.dir/src/sb6/sb6shader.cpp.o
[  6%] Building C object CMakeFiles/sb6.dir/src/sb6/gl3w.c.o
Linking CXX static library lib/libsb6.a
[  6%] Built target sb6
Scanning dependencies of target alienrain
[  7%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/alienrain.dir/src/alienrain/alienrain.cpp.o
Linking CXX executable bin/alienrain
CMakeFiles/alienrain.dir/src/alienrain/alienrain.cpp.o: In function `sb6::application::run(sb6::application*)':
alienrain.cpp:(.text._ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_[_ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_]+0x21): undefined reference to `glfwInit'
alienrain.cpp:(.text._ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_[_ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_]+0x7a): undefined reference to `glfwOpenWindowHint'
alienrain.cpp:(.text._ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_[_ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_]+0x90): undefined reference to `glfwOpenWindowHint'
alienrain.cpp:(.text._ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_[_ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_]+0x9f): undefined reference to `glfwOpenWindowHint'
alienrain.cpp:(.text._ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_[_ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_]+0xae): undefined reference to `glfwOpenWindowHint'
alienrain.cpp:(.text._ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_[_ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_]+0xc4): undefined reference to `glfwOpenWindowHint'
CMakeFiles/alienrain.dir/src/alienrain/alienrain.cpp.o:alienrain.cpp:(.text._ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_[_ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_]+0xee): more undefined references to `glfwOpenWindowHint' follow
CMakeFiles/alienrain.dir/src/alienrain/alienrain.cpp.o: In function `sb6::application::run(sb6::application*)':
alienrain.cpp:(.text._ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_[_ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_]+0x12c): undefined reference to `glfwGetDesktopMode'
alienrain.cpp:(.text._ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_[_ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_]+0x18e): undefined reference to `glfwOpenWindow'
alienrain.cpp:(.text._ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_[_ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_]+0x1a8): undefined reference to `glfwSwapInterval'
alienrain.cpp:(.text._ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_[_ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_]+0x1f2): undefined reference to `glfwOpenWindow'
alienrain.cpp:(.text._ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_[_ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_]+0x22e): undefined reference to `glfwSetWindowTitle'
alienrain.cpp:(.text._ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_[_ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_]+0x238): undefined reference to `glfwSetWindowSizeCallback'
alienrain.cpp:(.text._ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_[_ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_]+0x242): undefined reference to `glfwSetKeyCallback'
alienrain.cpp:(.text._ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_[_ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_]+0x24c): undefined reference to `glfwSetMouseButtonCallback'
alienrain.cpp:(.text._ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_[_ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_]+0x256): undefined reference to `glfwSetMousePosCallback'
alienrain.cpp:(.text._ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_[_ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_]+0x260): undefined reference to `glfwSetMouseWheelCallback'
alienrain.cpp:(.text._ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_[_ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_]+0x277): undefined reference to `glfwEnable'
alienrain.cpp:(.text._ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_[_ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_]+0x27e): undefined reference to `glfwDisable'
alienrain.cpp:(.text._ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_[_ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_]+0x28f): undefined reference to `glfwGetWindowParam'
alienrain.cpp:(.text._ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_[_ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_]+0x373): undefined reference to `glfwGetTime'
alienrain.cpp:(.text._ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_[_ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_]+0x393): undefined reference to `glfwSwapBuffers'
alienrain.cpp:(.text._ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_[_ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_]+0x39d): undefined reference to `glfwGetKey'
alienrain.cpp:(.text._ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_[_ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_]+0x3bd): undefined reference to `glfwGetWindowParam'
alienrain.cpp:(.text._ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_[_ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_]+0x3f5): undefined reference to `glfwTerminate'
lib/libsb6.a(gl3w.c.o): In function `open_libgl':
gl3w.c:(.text+0xf): undefined reference to `dlopen'
lib/libsb6.a(gl3w.c.o): In function `close_libgl':
gl3w.c:(.text+0x2b): undefined reference to `dlclose'
lib/libsb6.a(gl3w.c.o): In function `get_proc':
gl3w.c:(.text+0x45): undefined reference to `glXGetProcAddress'
gl3w.c:(.text+0x66): undefined reference to `dlsym'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [bin/alienrain] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/alienrain.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

What am I missing? As far as I can tell I have all the dependencies installed already.

Comment: Quite a lot, apparently. You may need to add `-ldl` for `dlopen` to be resolved, `-lGL` for `glXGetProcAddress`. I will admit I do not know the first thing about CMake, I still use gmake so I could not begin to tell you how to add those linker flags unfortunately. As for the GLFW stuff, the names imply GLFW2. Are you sure you didn't install GLFW3 thinking it would satisfy your dependencies? They're not compatible, lots of stuff changed.

Comment: Yeah... This stuff seems to have quite the hostile learning curve. Not only is c++ an epic language in itself, but even all the stuff surrounding it in regard to compiling and linking and makefiles and headers and so on is... mind boggling.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is a bug in CMakeLists.txt at line 13.
(https://github.com/openglsuperbible/sb6code/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt)

Change "elif (UNIX)" to "elseif (UNIX)",and it will be ok.

Reference:
https://www.opengl.org/discussion_boards/showthread.php/183902-SuperBible-6th-ed-Cannot-link-the-Linux-examples

Answer (score 1):

as @AndonMColeman suggested, you need `-lGL` and `-ldl` *in the end* of the libraries list. Use [`target_link_libraries`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.12/cmake.html#command%3atarget_link_libraries) macro for this.

If you provide CMakeLists.txt from your project it would be much easier to suggest you an exact string to add/change ;)