# OpenGL 4.3 development setup in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: c++, linux, opengl, ubuntu

I've just started working my way through the OpenGL SuperBible 6th ed and am having a very hard time getting any of the samples to compile on Ubuntu 14.04. I installed the dev packages dependencies:

```
sudo apt-get install xorg-dev libglu1-mesa-dev libglfw-dev nvidia-331-dev cmake
```

I grabbed gl3w from skaslev's github, ran the python script and then sudo copied gl3w.h and glcorearb.h to /usr/include/GL/

I grabbed the samples from the SuperBible github and the media files, unzipped the media files into bin/media. Then I went back to the root of the sb6 files (the folder is called sb6code_2013_11_10 in my case) where and ran:

```
cmake .
make
```

*cmake* works fine, but *make* throws:

```
[  6%] Built target sb6
Linking CXX executable bin/alienrain
CMakeFiles/alienrain.dir/src/alienrain/alienrain.cpp.o: In function `sb6::application::run(sb6::application*)':
alienrain.cpp:(.text._ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_[_ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_]+0x21): undefined reference to `glfwInit'
alienrain.cpp:(.text._ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_[_ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_]+0x7a): undefined reference to `glfwOpenWindowHint'
alienrain.cpp:(.text._ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_[_ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_]+0x90): undefined reference to `glfwOpenWindowHint'
alienrain.cpp:(.text._ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_[_ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_]+0x9f): undefined reference to `glfwOpenWindowHint'
alienrain.cpp:(.text._ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_[_ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_]+0xae): undefined reference to `glfwOpenWindowHint'
alienrain.cpp:(.text._ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_[_ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_]+0xc4): undefined reference to `glfwOpenWindowHint'
CMakeFiles/alienrain.dir/src/alienrain/alienrain.cpp.o:alienrain.cpp:(.text._ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_[_ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_]+0xee): more undefined references to `glfwOpenWindowHint' follow
CMakeFiles/alienrain.dir/src/alienrain/alienrain.cpp.o: In function `sb6::application::run(sb6::application*)':
alienrain.cpp:(.text._ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_[_ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_]+0x12c): undefined reference to `glfwGetDesktopMode'
alienrain.cpp:(.text._ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_[_ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_]+0x18e): undefined reference to `glfwOpenWindow'
alienrain.cpp:(.text._ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_[_ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_]+0x1a8): undefined reference to `glfwSwapInterval'
alienrain.cpp:(.text._ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_[_ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_]+0x1f2): undefined reference to `glfwOpenWindow'
alienrain.cpp:(.text._ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_[_ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_]+0x22e): undefined reference to `glfwSetWindowTitle'
alienrain.cpp:(.text._ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_[_ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_]+0x238): undefined reference to `glfwSetWindowSizeCallback'
alienrain.cpp:(.text._ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_[_ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_]+0x242): undefined reference to `glfwSetKeyCallback'
alienrain.cpp:(.text._ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_[_ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_]+0x24c): undefined reference to `glfwSetMouseButtonCallback'
alienrain.cpp:(.text._ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_[_ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_]+0x256): undefined reference to `glfwSetMousePosCallback'
alienrain.cpp:(.text._ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_[_ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_]+0x260): undefined reference to `glfwSetMouseWheelCallback'
alienrain.cpp:(.text._ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_[_ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_]+0x277): undefined reference to `glfwEnable'
alienrain.cpp:(.text._ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_[_ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_]+0x27e): undefined reference to `glfwDisable'
alienrain.cpp:(.text._ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_[_ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_]+0x28f): undefined reference to `glfwGetWindowParam'
alienrain.cpp:(.text._ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_[_ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_]+0x373): undefined reference to `glfwGetTime'
alienrain.cpp:(.text._ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_[_ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_]+0x393): undefined reference to `glfwSwapBuffers'
alienrain.cpp:(.text._ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_[_ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_]+0x39d): undefined reference to `glfwGetKey'
alienrain.cpp:(.text._ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_[_ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_]+0x3bd): undefined reference to `glfwGetWindowParam'
alienrain.cpp:(.text._ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_[_ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_]+0x3f5): undefined reference to `glfwTerminate'
lib/libsb6.a(gl3w.c.o): In function `open_libgl':
gl3w.c:(.text+0xf): undefined reference to `dlopen'
lib/libsb6.a(gl3w.c.o): In function `close_libgl':
gl3w.c:(.text+0x2b): undefined reference to `dlclose'
lib/libsb6.a(gl3w.c.o): In function `get_proc':
gl3w.c:(.text+0x45): undefined reference to `glXGetProcAddress'
gl3w.c:(.text+0x66): undefined reference to `dlsym'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [bin/alienrain] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/alienrain.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

So I decided to try and write my own small program based on Listing 2.1 in the book:

```
#include "sb6.h"

class my_application : public sb6::application
{
    void init()
    {
        static const char title[] = "OpenGL SuperBible - Listing 2.1";

        sb6::application::init();

        memcpy(info.title, title, sizeof(title));
    }

    void render(double currentTime)
    {
        static const GLfloat red[] = {1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f};
        glClearBufferfv(GL_COLOR, 0, red);
    }


};

DECLARE_MAIN(my_application)
```

Then I try to compile it:

```
g++ listing2.1.cpp -o listing2.1 -lGL -lGLU -lX11 -lglfw -D_LINUX
```

But that gives me a different set of errors:

```
In file included from sb6.h:65:0,
                 from listing2.1.cpp:1:
GL/gl3w.h:546:8: error: ‘PFNGLGETNMAPDVARBPROC’ does not name a type
 extern PFNGLGETNMAPDVARBPROC gl3wGetnMapdvARB;
        ^
GL/gl3w.h:547:8: error: ‘PFNGLGETNMAPFVARBPROC’ does not name a type
 extern PFNGLGETNMAPFVARBPROC gl3wGetnMapfvARB;
        ^
GL/gl3w.h:548:8: error: ‘PFNGLGETNMAPIVARBPROC’ does not name a type
 extern PFNGLGETNMAPIVARBPROC gl3wGetnMapivARB;
        ^
GL/gl3w.h:549:8: error: ‘PFNGLGETNPIXELMAPFVARBPROC’ does not name a type
 extern PFNGLGETNPIXELMAPFVARBPROC gl3wGetnPixelMapfvARB;
        ^
GL/gl3w.h:550:8: error: ‘PFNGLGETNPIXELMAPUIVARBPROC’ does not name a type
 extern PFNGLGETNPIXELMAPUIVARBPROC gl3wGetnPixelMapuivARB;
        ^
GL/gl3w.h:551:8: error: ‘PFNGLGETNPIXELMAPUSVARBPROC’ does not name a type
 extern PFNGLGETNPIXELMAPUSVARBPROC gl3wGetnPixelMapusvARB;
        ^
GL/gl3w.h:552:8: error: ‘PFNGLGETNPOLYGONSTIPPLEARBPROC’ does not name a type
 extern PFNGLGETNPOLYGONSTIPPLEARBPROC gl3wGetnPolygonStippleARB;
        ^
GL/gl3w.h:553:8: error: ‘PFNGLGETNCOLORTABLEARBPROC’ does not name a type
 extern PFNGLGETNCOLORTABLEARBPROC gl3wGetnColorTableARB;
        ^
GL/gl3w.h:554:8: error: ‘PFNGLGETNCONVOLUTIONFILTERARBPROC’ does not name a type
 extern PFNGLGETNCONVOLUTIONFILTERARBPROC gl3wGetnConvolutionFilterARB;
        ^
GL/gl3w.h:555:8: error: ‘PFNGLGETNSEPARABLEFILTERARBPROC’ does not name a type
 extern PFNGLGETNSEPARABLEFILTERARBPROC gl3wGetnSeparableFilterARB;
        ^
GL/gl3w.h:556:8: error: ‘PFNGLGETNHISTOGRAMARBPROC’ does not name a type
 extern PFNGLGETNHISTOGRAMARBPROC gl3wGetnHistogramARB;
        ^
GL/gl3w.h:557:8: error: ‘PFNGLGETNMINMAXARBPROC’ does not name a type
 extern PFNGLGETNMINMAXARBPROC gl3wGetnMinmaxARB;
        ^
```

I checked in sb6.h that gl3w.h is included before any of the OpenGL dependencies and that's true so I'll really not sure what to try next. Seems to be a linking problem but it's been a long time since I've been developing in C++ and I'm not sure what to try next.

**Update**

I followed didierc's suggestion and found that there was a sb6code_2013_11_10/include/GL folder with gl3w.h and glcorearb.h. I temporarily moved the GL folder out of sb6code_2013_11_10/include and then ran *cmake* and *make* again and then received the following error:

```
Scanning dependencies of target sb6
[  1%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/sb6.dir/src/sb6/sb6.cpp.o
In file included from /home/lewa/workspace-cpp/opengl-superbible/sb6code_2013_11_10/include/sb6ext.h:29:0,
                 from /home/lewa/workspace-cpp/opengl-superbible/sb6code_2013_11_10/include/sb6.h:71,
                 from /home/lewa/workspace-cpp/opengl-superbible/sb6code_2013_11_10/src/sb6/sb6.cpp:26:
/usr/include/GL/glext.h:6184:181: error: conflicting declaration ‘typedef void (* PFNGLCLEARNAMEDBUFFERSUBDATAEXTPROC)(GLuint, GLenum, GLsizeiptr, GLsizeiptr, GLenum, GLenum, const void*)’
 typedef void (APIENTRYP PFNGLCLEARNAMEDBUFFERSUBDATAEXTPROC) (GLuint buffer, GLenum internalformat, GLsizeiptr offset, GLsizeiptr size, GLenum format, GLenum type, const void *data);
                                                                                                                                                                                     ^
In file included from /usr/include/GL/gl3w.h:4:0,
                 from /home/lewa/workspace-cpp/opengl-superbible/sb6code_2013_11_10/include/sb6.h:65,
                 from /home/lewa/workspace-cpp/opengl-superbible/sb6code_2013_11_10/src/sb6/sb6.cpp:26:
/usr/include/GL/glcorearb.h:4348:25: error: ‘PFNGLCLEARNAMEDBUFFERSUBDATAEXTPROC’ has a previous declaration as ‘typedef void (* PFNGLCLEARNAMEDBUFFERSUBDATAEXTPROC)(GLuint, GLenum, GLenum, GLenum, GLsizeiptr, GLsizeiptr, const void*)’
 typedef void (APIENTRYP PFNGLCLEARNAMEDBUFFERSUBDATAEXTPROC) (GLuint buffer, GLenum internalformat, GLenum format, GLenum type, GLsizeiptr offset, GLsizeiptr size, const void *data);
                         ^
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/sb6.dir/src/sb6/sb6.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/sb6.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Then I thought "Ok, then maybe I'll try using the gl3w.h and glcorearb.h that came with the sb6 package." So I restored the GL folder and then deleted the gl3w.h and glcorearb.h I previously generated with the python script and placed in /usr/include/GL. After a *cmake* and *make* I then get this error:

```
[  1%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/sb6.dir/src/sb6/sb6.cpp.o
[  2%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/sb6.dir/src/sb6/sb6ktx.cpp.o
[  3%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/sb6.dir/src/sb6/sb6object.cpp.o
[  5%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/sb6.dir/src/sb6/sb6shader.cpp.o
[  6%] Building C object CMakeFiles/sb6.dir/src/sb6/gl3w.c.o
Linking CXX static library lib/libsb6.a
[  6%] Built target sb6
Linking CXX executable bin/alienrain
CMakeFiles/alienrain.dir/src/alienrain/alienrain.cpp.o: In function `sb6::application::run(sb6::application*)':
alienrain.cpp:(.text._ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_[_ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_]+0x21): undefined reference to `glfwInit'
alienrain.cpp:(.text._ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_[_ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_]+0x7a): undefined reference to `glfwOpenWindowHint'
alienrain.cpp:(.text._ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_[_ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_]+0x90): undefined reference to `glfwOpenWindowHint'
alienrain.cpp:(.text._ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_[_ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_]+0x9f): undefined reference to `glfwOpenWindowHint'
alienrain.cpp:(.text._ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_[_ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_]+0xae): undefined reference to `glfwOpenWindowHint'
alienrain.cpp:(.text._ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_[_ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_]+0xc4): undefined reference to `glfwOpenWindowHint'
CMakeFiles/alienrain.dir/src/alienrain/alienrain.cpp.o:alienrain.cpp:(.text._ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_[_ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_]+0xee): more undefined references to `glfwOpenWindowHint' follow
CMakeFiles/alienrain.dir/src/alienrain/alienrain.cpp.o: In function `sb6::application::run(sb6::application*)':
alienrain.cpp:(.text._ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_[_ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_]+0x12c): undefined reference to `glfwGetDesktopMode'
alienrain.cpp:(.text._ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_[_ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_]+0x18e): undefined reference to `glfwOpenWindow'
alienrain.cpp:(.text._ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_[_ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_]+0x1a8): undefined reference to `glfwSwapInterval'
alienrain.cpp:(.text._ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_[_ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_]+0x1f2): undefined reference to `glfwOpenWindow'
alienrain.cpp:(.text._ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_[_ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_]+0x22e): undefined reference to `glfwSetWindowTitle'
alienrain.cpp:(.text._ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_[_ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_]+0x238): undefined reference to `glfwSetWindowSizeCallback'
alienrain.cpp:(.text._ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_[_ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_]+0x242): undefined reference to `glfwSetKeyCallback'
alienrain.cpp:(.text._ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_[_ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_]+0x24c): undefined reference to `glfwSetMouseButtonCallback'
alienrain.cpp:(.text._ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_[_ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_]+0x256): undefined reference to `glfwSetMousePosCallback'
alienrain.cpp:(.text._ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_[_ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_]+0x260): undefined reference to `glfwSetMouseWheelCallback'
alienrain.cpp:(.text._ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_[_ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_]+0x277): undefined reference to `glfwEnable'
alienrain.cpp:(.text._ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_[_ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_]+0x27e): undefined reference to `glfwDisable'
alienrain.cpp:(.text._ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_[_ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_]+0x28f): undefined reference to `glfwGetWindowParam'
alienrain.cpp:(.text._ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_[_ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_]+0x373): undefined reference to `glfwGetTime'
alienrain.cpp:(.text._ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_[_ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_]+0x393): undefined reference to `glfwSwapBuffers'
alienrain.cpp:(.text._ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_[_ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_]+0x39d): undefined reference to `glfwGetKey'
alienrain.cpp:(.text._ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_[_ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_]+0x3bd): undefined reference to `glfwGetWindowParam'
alienrain.cpp:(.text._ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_[_ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_]+0x3f5): undefined reference to `glfwTerminate'
lib/libsb6.a(gl3w.c.o): In function `open_libgl':
gl3w.c:(.text+0xf): undefined reference to `dlopen'
lib/libsb6.a(gl3w.c.o): In function `close_libgl':
gl3w.c:(.text+0x2b): undefined reference to `dlclose'
lib/libsb6.a(gl3w.c.o): In function `get_proc':
gl3w.c:(.text+0x45): undefined reference to `glXGetProcAddress'
gl3w.c:(.text+0x66): undefined reference to `dlsym'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [bin/alienrain] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/alienrain.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

So I'm not sure if that's progress but at least is exposes some of the snakes. Any advice on what to do next would be appreciated!

**Update 2**

Here's what I get from running *make VERBOSE=1* with the GL folder intact (ie just as it was when I downloaded the sb6 files, but I also have glw3.h and glcorearb.h in /usr/include/GL):

```
/usr/bin/cmake -H/home/lewa/workspace-cpp/opengl-superbible/sb6code_2013_11_10 -B/home/lewa/workspace-cpp/opengl-superbible/sb6code_2013_11_10 --check-build-system CMakeFiles/Makefile.cmake 0
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_start /home/lewa/workspace-cpp/opengl-superbible/sb6code_2013_11_10/CMakeFiles /home/lewa/workspace-cpp/opengl-superbible/sb6code_2013_11_10/CMakeFiles/progress.marks
make -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 all
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/lewa/workspace-cpp/opengl-superbible/sb6code_2013_11_10'
make -f CMakeFiles/sb6.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/sb6.dir/depend
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/lewa/workspace-cpp/opengl-superbible/sb6code_2013_11_10'
cd /home/lewa/workspace-cpp/opengl-superbible/sb6code_2013_11_10 && /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_depends "Unix Makefiles" /home/lewa/workspace-cpp/opengl-superbible/sb6code_2013_11_10 /home/lewa/workspace-cpp/opengl-superbible/sb6code_2013_11_10 /home/lewa/workspace-cpp/opengl-superbible/sb6code_2013_11_10 /home/lewa/workspace-cpp/opengl-superbible/sb6code_2013_11_10 /home/lewa/workspace-cpp/opengl-superbible/sb6code_2013_11_10/CMakeFiles/sb6.dir/DependInfo.cmake --color=
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/lewa/workspace-cpp/opengl-superbible/sb6code_2013_11_10'
make -f CMakeFiles/sb6.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/sb6.dir/build
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/lewa/workspace-cpp/opengl-superbible/sb6code_2013_11_10'
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_report /home/lewa/workspace-cpp/opengl-superbible/sb6code_2013_11_10/CMakeFiles 51
[  1%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/sb6.dir/src/sb6/sb6.cpp.o
/usr/bin/c++    -D_LINUX -I/home/lewa/workspace-cpp/opengl-superbible/sb6code_2013_11_10/include -I/home/lewa/workspace-cpp/opengl-superbible/sb6code_2013_11_10/extern/glfw-2.7.6/include    -o CMakeFiles/sb6.dir/src/sb6/sb6.cpp.o -c /home/lewa/workspace-cpp/opengl-superbible/sb6code_2013_11_10/src/sb6/sb6.cpp
Linking CXX static library lib/libsb6.a
/usr/bin/cmake -P CMakeFiles/sb6.dir/cmake_clean_target.cmake
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/sb6.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/bin/ar cr lib/libsb6.a  CMakeFiles/sb6.dir/src/sb6/sb6.cpp.o CMakeFiles/sb6.dir/src/sb6/sb6ktx.cpp.o CMakeFiles/sb6.dir/src/sb6/sb6object.cpp.o CMakeFiles/sb6.dir/src/sb6/sb6shader.cpp.o CMakeFiles/sb6.dir/src/sb6/gl3w.c.o
/usr/bin/ranlib lib/libsb6.a
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/lewa/workspace-cpp/opengl-superbible/sb6code_2013_11_10'
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_report /home/lewa/workspace-cpp/opengl-superbible/sb6code_2013_11_10/CMakeFiles  51 52 53 54 55
[  6%] Built target sb6
make -f CMakeFiles/alienrain.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/alienrain.dir/depend
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/lewa/workspace-cpp/opengl-superbible/sb6code_2013_11_10'
cd /home/lewa/workspace-cpp/opengl-superbible/sb6code_2013_11_10 && /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_depends "Unix Makefiles" /home/lewa/workspace-cpp/opengl-superbible/sb6code_2013_11_10 /home/lewa/workspace-cpp/opengl-superbible/sb6code_2013_11_10 /home/lewa/workspace-cpp/opengl-superbible/sb6code_2013_11_10 /home/lewa/workspace-cpp/opengl-superbible/sb6code_2013_11_10 /home/lewa/workspace-cpp/opengl-superbible/sb6code_2013_11_10/CMakeFiles/alienrain.dir/DependInfo.cmake --color=
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/lewa/workspace-cpp/opengl-superbible/sb6code_2013_11_10'
make -f CMakeFiles/alienrain.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/alienrain.dir/build
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/lewa/workspace-cpp/opengl-superbible/sb6code_2013_11_10'
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_report /home/lewa/workspace-cpp/opengl-superbible/sb6code_2013_11_10/CMakeFiles 1
[  7%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/alienrain.dir/src/alienrain/alienrain.cpp.o
/usr/bin/c++    -D_LINUX -I/home/lewa/workspace-cpp/opengl-superbible/sb6code_2013_11_10/include -I/home/lewa/workspace-cpp/opengl-superbible/sb6code_2013_11_10/extern/glfw-2.7.6/include    -o CMakeFiles/alienrain.dir/src/alienrain/alienrain.cpp.o -c /home/lewa/workspace-cpp/opengl-superbible/sb6code_2013_11_10/src/alienrain/alienrain.cpp
Linking CXX executable bin/alienrain
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/alienrain.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/bin/c++    -D_LINUX    CMakeFiles/alienrain.dir/src/alienrain/alienrain.cpp.o  -o bin/alienrain  -L/home/lewa/workspace-cpp/opengl-superbible/sb6code_2013_11_10/lib -rdynamic lib/libsb6.a -Wl,-rpath,/home/lewa/workspace-cpp/opengl-superbible/sb6code_2013_11_10/lib 
CMakeFiles/alienrain.dir/src/alienrain/alienrain.cpp.o: In function `sb6::application::run(sb6::application*)':
alienrain.cpp:(.text._ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_[_ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_]+0x21): undefined reference to `glfwInit'
alienrain.cpp:(.text._ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_[_ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_]+0x7a): undefined reference to `glfwOpenWindowHint'
alienrain.cpp:(.text._ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_[_ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_]+0x90): undefined reference to `glfwOpenWindowHint'
alienrain.cpp:(.text._ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_[_ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_]+0x9f): undefined reference to `glfwOpenWindowHint'
alienrain.cpp:(.text._ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_[_ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_]+0xae): undefined reference to `glfwOpenWindowHint'
alienrain.cpp:(.text._ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_[_ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_]+0xc4): undefined reference to `glfwOpenWindowHint'
CMakeFiles/alienrain.dir/src/alienrain/alienrain.cpp.o:alienrain.cpp:(.text._ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_[_ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_]+0xee): more undefined references to `glfwOpenWindowHint' follow
CMakeFiles/alienrain.dir/src/alienrain/alienrain.cpp.o: In function `sb6::application::run(sb6::application*)':
alienrain.cpp:(.text._ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_[_ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_]+0x12c): undefined reference to `glfwGetDesktopMode'
alienrain.cpp:(.text._ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_[_ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_]+0x18e): undefined reference to `glfwOpenWindow'
alienrain.cpp:(.text._ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_[_ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_]+0x1a8): undefined reference to `glfwSwapInterval'
alienrain.cpp:(.text._ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_[_ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_]+0x1f2): undefined reference to `glfwOpenWindow'
alienrain.cpp:(.text._ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_[_ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_]+0x22e): undefined reference to `glfwSetWindowTitle'
alienrain.cpp:(.text._ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_[_ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_]+0x238): undefined reference to `glfwSetWindowSizeCallback'
alienrain.cpp:(.text._ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_[_ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_]+0x242): undefined reference to `glfwSetKeyCallback'
alienrain.cpp:(.text._ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_[_ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_]+0x24c): undefined reference to `glfwSetMouseButtonCallback'
alienrain.cpp:(.text._ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_[_ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_]+0x256): undefined reference to `glfwSetMousePosCallback'
alienrain.cpp:(.text._ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_[_ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_]+0x260): undefined reference to `glfwSetMouseWheelCallback'
alienrain.cpp:(.text._ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_[_ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_]+0x277): undefined reference to `glfwEnable'
alienrain.cpp:(.text._ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_[_ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_]+0x27e): undefined reference to `glfwDisable'
alienrain.cpp:(.text._ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_[_ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_]+0x28f): undefined reference to `glfwGetWindowParam'
alienrain.cpp:(.text._ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_[_ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_]+0x373): undefined reference to `glfwGetTime'
alienrain.cpp:(.text._ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_[_ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_]+0x393): undefined reference to `glfwSwapBuffers'
alienrain.cpp:(.text._ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_[_ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_]+0x39d): undefined reference to `glfwGetKey'
alienrain.cpp:(.text._ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_[_ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_]+0x3bd): undefined reference to `glfwGetWindowParam'
alienrain.cpp:(.text._ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_[_ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_]+0x3f5): undefined reference to `glfwTerminate'
lib/libsb6.a(gl3w.c.o): In function `open_libgl':
gl3w.c:(.text+0xf): undefined reference to `dlopen'
lib/libsb6.a(gl3w.c.o): In function `close_libgl':
gl3w.c:(.text+0x2b): undefined reference to `dlclose'
lib/libsb6.a(gl3w.c.o): In function `get_proc':
gl3w.c:(.text+0x45): undefined reference to `glXGetProcAddress'
gl3w.c:(.text+0x66): undefined reference to `dlsym'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [bin/alienrain] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/lewa/workspace-cpp/opengl-superbible/sb6code_2013_11_10'
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/alienrain.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/lewa/workspace-cpp/opengl-superbible/sb6code_2013_11_10'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

**Update 3**

I was able to find a solution to the build problem with the sb6 sample code. It turns out there is a error in the CMakeLists.txt included with the sample code where on line 13 the 'elif (UNIX)' should be 'elseif (UNIX)'. See references:

[trouble trying to build opengl superbible example code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23024789/trouble-trying-to-build-opengl-superbible-example-code?rq=1)

https://github.com/openglsuperbible/sb6code/issues/12

https://github.com/openglsuperbible/sb6code/issues/8

With that fix the sb6 sample code now compiles for me. However, when I try to use sb6.h in my own sample code (listed in *my_application* above) I still get

```
In file included from sb6ext.h:29:0,
                 from sb6.h:71,
                 from listing2.1.cpp:1:
/usr/include/GL/glext.h:6184:181: error: conflicting declaration ‘typedef void (* PFNGLCLEARNAMEDBUFFERSUBDATAEXTPROC)(GLuint, GLenum, GLsizeiptr, GLsizeiptr, GLenum, GLenum, const void*)’
 typedef void (APIENTRYP PFNGLCLEARNAMEDBUFFERSUBDATAEXTPROC) (GLuint buffer, GLenum internalformat, GLsizeiptr offset, GLsizeiptr size, GLenum format, GLenum type, const void *data);
                                                                                                                                                                                     ^
In file included from /usr/include/GL/gl3w.h:4:0,
                 from sb6.h:65,
                 from listing2.1.cpp:1:
/usr/include/GL/glcorearb.h:4348:25: error: ‘PFNGLCLEARNAMEDBUFFERSUBDATAEXTPROC’ has a previous declaration as ‘typedef void (* PFNGLCLEARNAMEDBUFFERSUBDATAEXTPROC)(GLuint, GLenum, GLenum, GLenum, GLsizeiptr, GLsizeiptr, const void*)’
 typedef void (APIENTRYP PFNGLCLEARNAMEDBUFFERSUBDATAEXTPROC) (GLuint buffer, GLenum internalformat, GLenum format, GLenum type, GLsizeiptr offset, GLsizeiptr size, const void *data);
                         ^
```

Comment: Perhaps you have different versions of `glcorearb.h` confflicting: check in `/usr/include/GL` or `/usr/local/include/GL` (or maybe other directories in your `$PATH`)  to see if there's one installed there. `sb6.h` is probably hoping to find the one in its own subdir, which contains the `*define` gcc complains about.

Comment: Tried it - post updated

Comment: You're not linking with `glfw3`, `GLX` and `dl`. `make VERBOSE=1` should show you actual command being issued; attach it to question if you can't make sense out of it. If you can compile and run any glfw example - your setup is ok.

Comment: Updated. How do I link glfw in this case? Thanks for the help!

Comment: I solved the compilation problem with sb6 code but still have a problem compiling my own sample. See update.

Comment: glcorearb.h and glext.h are incompatible. Perhaps they were when library in question was written, but surely current versions don't. Fixing this conflict may be nontrivial though (depending on library itself. you can start with removing one of includes, but it may raise another errors), but I honestly don't believe you need some proxy library to learn GL.

Comment: Perhaps it means you shouldn't use the sb6 toolkit? It seems they bring more problems than they solve. Have you considered alternatives (if any)?

Comment: Yeah perhaps you're right; I thought it would be easier to learn OpenGL by following along with the examples in the book but perhaps that's not true and I should not rely on their library in the first place. As an alternative I think I'll take a look at http://www.arcsynthesis.org/gltut/ and see if those tutorials are easier to work with.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to solve the sb6 sample code compilation problems by fixing a bug in CMakeLists.txt where on line 13 the 'elif (UNIX)' should be 'elseif (UNIX)'. See the following for references:

[trouble trying to build opengl superbible example code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23024789/trouble-trying-to-build-opengl-superbible-example-code?rq=1)

https://github.com/openglsuperbible/sb6code/issues/12

https://github.com/openglsuperbible/sb6code/issues/8

I have not solve my compilation problems when I use sb6.h in my own code yet but will update this answer when I do

Comment: Update: I have still not resolved the conflicting declaration error when using sb6.h in my own code. In fact, I've stopped using the SuperBible altogether and am instead reading Anton Gerdelan's [book](http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00LAMQYF2/ref=as_li_tl?ie=UTF8&camp=1789&creative=390957&creativeASIN=B00LAMQYF2&linkCode=as2&tag=tekso-20&linkId=BADINE62NXK4JTN2) and [website](http://antongerdelan.net/opengl/index.html) as well as the [arcsynthesis tutorials](http://www.arcsynthesis.org/gltut/) which are all much more accessible from a code and readability stand point.